# Start an Activity with Activity name as a variable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I am trying to start an activity from a snackbar with a String as the Activity name.

The snackbar code is:

```
private void showSnackbar(View view, String massgae, String action, final String intent) {
    Snackbar.make(view, massgae, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(action, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent myIntent = null;
                    try {
                        myIntent = new Intent(context, Class.forName(intent));
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            })
            .setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setDuration(5000)
            .show();
}
```

and I'm calling it with this:

```
showSnackbar(llMain, getResources().getString(R.string.sbUserNotFound), getResources().getString(R.string.sbRegister), "Register.class");
```

When it loads I get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.toString()' on a null object reference.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that's a bad idea. Sorry to say. Class.forName() shouldn't be used like that.

If you want to customize which activity get started, send a variable such as Class and make it generic.

But if you truly stick with this implementation, then the reason it fails is because you have to pass the full package name to Class.forName(), and not add ".class" at the end of it.

So something like:

```
Class.forName("com.testapp.ui.Register");
```

Of course, you'll need to change the package name(s) to fit your own application.

Comment: im fairly new to android development and the ide suggested the Class.forname.
any better solution?

Comment: @NirGolan Rather than pass in a string intent, pass in a Class variable and pass that into the Intent constructor directly.

Comment: thanks. i have red your answer again and understood. instead of string intent a Class intent. its working now. thanks